# Dojo contentpane/tab parsing issue

Tags: parsing, tabs, widget, dojo

I am having issues parsing HTML markup into Dojo widgets. Here is what I am doing:

```
var tab = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    title: "xyz",
    parseOnLoad: false,   //I am doing this intentionally
    href: "some-relative-url"
});

tabPane.addChild(tab);
```

now, if I test this with parseOnLoad = true, I get my widgets loaded nicely. However, I am trying to process the HTML before it is turned into widgets. So I delayed the parsing by adding the parseOnLoad: false option. I binded a function to be called when my tab is loaded (i.e. the Ajax call is complete), like such:

```
dojo.connect (tab, "onDownloadEnd", myFunction);

function myFunction() {

   //manipulate the HTML code via this.content
   dojo.parser.parse(this);   //this doesn't do anything. I tried many variations!
}
```

So what happens when I do that is that I end up with the tab loaded but no widgets, just standard HTML controls. So why isn't the parser being triggered in this scenario and what can I do to make it work on my manipulated HTML?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure `this` in myFunction is a DOM node, and I think it has to be for `parse()` to do anything. Try `dojo.parser.parse(this.get("domNode"));`

Comment: Funny, I was just trying something similar and it worked but don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, so can I only use the comments here for now. This worked for me: dojo.parser.parse(this.domNode);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in that context is probably the `window` object, since you're not specifically setting the scope in your `connect` (from the code you posted I assume `myFunction()` is a free function, not a method.

You need to pass `dojo.parser.parse` a DOM node. Assuming `tab` is a widget, you can use `dojo.parser.parse(tab.domNode)` if the function is defined in the context of availability of `tab`. If `this` is scoped to the tab widget, then you can use `dojo.parser.parse(this.domNode)` as you say in your comment.

You can force the scope with the almighty powerful `dojo.hitch` :) Read the documentation [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hitch.html) and I recommend the [How `this` works](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) section from the [Javascript garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/).